# Can you use lower GBWP op amps for a filter requiring a higher GBWP by cascading op amps to get a higher bandwidth?

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

I was watching this youtube video [EEVblog video on cascading op amps for increased bandwidth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvT9hHG17tQ) , and I was wondering if this can be used for 2-pole filters, including filters that are made up of multiple 2 pole filters?

Most 2-pole active filters are made using a single op amp , so for example if I want to use the standard 1 Mhz GBWP op amp , and I am making a 2-pole filter , that requires a GBWP of more than 1 Mhz, can I just cascade multiple op amps together until I get the required GBWP needed?

Comment: "Can you use lower GBWP op amps for a filter requiring a higher GBWP by cascading op amps to get a higher bandwidth?" Yes, if you do it appropriately.

Comment: It may be simpler just to source a higher GBW amplifier though.

Comment: Not unless you define real specs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With difficulty.

The additional phase shift of the extra opamps can easily compromise stability.

Cascading opamps will not help characteristics such as slew-rate which will limit the large-signal capability.